# tufte-latex: MinionPro linespacing

Tags: fonts, typography, line-spacing, tufte

I would like to use MinionPro with the tufte-latex document class. However I do not know much about typography. I seems that MinionPro is smaller than the default Palatino for which tufte-latex was configured. I wonder if (and how) I should adjust the linespacing for MinionPro.

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[osf,onlytext,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
\section{Palatino}
\lipsum[1]
\section{MinionPro}
\fontbasefamily{MinionPro}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **tufte-latex** loads the package `setspace` so you can use the following commands: `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`, `\doublespacing`, and `\setstretch{<factor>}`. But I wouldn't change the linespacing.

Comment: By the way: tufte-latex is not very flexible and you seem to have a lot of things (fonts, biblatex, etc) you want customized. Maybe you should consider using a different document class and use a package like [`sidenotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) to emulate the features of tufte-latex.

Comment: I considered this. At the moment I am very happy with tufte-latex since its sidenotes, marginnotes and captions work flawlessly and I experienced much more problems trying to setup these manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use the following snippet from `11size.clo` which looks decent since it has the same size than the original Palatino font in 10pt.

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
    \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
    \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
    \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
    \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
    \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
    \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\renewcommand\small{%
    \@setfontsize\small\@xpt\@xiipt
    \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
    \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
    \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
        \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
        \parsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
        \itemsep \parsep}%
    \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
    \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
    \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
    \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
    \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
        \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
        \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
        \itemsep \parsep}%
    \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9.5}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
```